# working with a date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i know this query is not right, and kind of jumbled. but it sort of displays what i want to do. what I'm trying to figure out is how to use the current date in a query. basically i want to subtract a stored date from the current date and if the result is < 30 do something. but i obviously don't know how to work with dates.... i am assuming that it shouldn't be a char value, but if i just use sys date oracle gives me a table error.

```
select e.STUDENT_ID
   from COURSES c, CLASS_ENROLLMENT e, (SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as now
   FROM DUAL) t
   where t - c.END_DATE <= 30;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your query is correct this should solve your date problem:

```
select e.STUDENT_ID
  from COURSES c, CLASS_ENROLLMENT e
 where to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-RR')) - c.END_DATE <= 30;
```

You don't need to select sysdate from dual unless you just want to display it for one reason or another without querying something else. You can just specify it as sysdate as part of a any query anywhere.

The reason I converted it to a character and then to a date in this case is just to remove the time from sysdate, this way it will be 30 days from the given day, regardless of time. If you didn't care about time you could just say sysdate - c.end_date <=30

As an fyi - you probably need to add join conditions between the COURSES and CLASS_ENROLLMENT tables. The above should not result in a sql error and should do you want with respect to the date of the records, but it's unlikely to be what you want (in full).

Comment: That code depends on the client using the default date format.  It would be safer to use `trunc(sysdate) - c.END_DATE <= 30`